# How Can I Explain a Teleportation Machine?

Tags: science-fiction, technological-development, teleportation

In my world, teleporters have been developed. I'm having trouble trying to explain it and its invention. This is due to the fact that it is one of the only extremely futuristic technologies in my story.

The way teleporters currently work in my story is they are a telephone booth-sized device that you type in coordinates or a teleporter number/code (kind of like calling a phone number) and then you enter it and teleport.

So I have a couple questions:

1. What are some ways I can explain the development of teleporters in a scientific-sounding way?
2. Other than sophisticated robots, magnetically levitating cars, and advanced prosthetics, my world is probably only 10 years in the future in terms of technology. So, how can I explain how and why the teleporter was invented before, for example, faster-than-light travel?

**Good answers will address the two questions above.**

---

I have looked into teleportation, but the field is a little bit over my head and I don't want to learn everything about science that has ever science-d.

Comment: "[Why would someone/something X?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130#6338)" questions are generally off-topic as too broad, [too story-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300), or [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6437/40609). We need to convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609). (\*continued\*)

Comment: Please take the time to review our meta post about [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609).  You need to provide a clear explanation of the limitations/conditions concerning your technology and an equally clear explanation of how you will judge the best answer.

Comment: One question at a time.  Once you decide on which question you actually want to ask,  then work on ***not*** making it the scavenge for opinions these questions currently are.  This should be left closed until these serious issues are resolved.

Comment: @elemtilas There are constructive ways of saying things, you know.

Comment: @JBH Thank you, that link is very helpful and should help me avoid this issue for future questions.

Comment: I'm sorry. Would you actually prefer the *unconstructive* method?

Comment: @elemtilas What was constructive about how you said that? Did you provide me any information or means to help me to improve?

Comment: I pointed out the issues with your query. You ask too many questions.  After you pick one and edit to reflect your decision, I'll be more than happy to vote to reopen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quantum entanglement is (roughly) when two particles have the same quantum state regardless of the space between. They change instantly and simultaneously. While it is currently impossible to transmit classical information this way, in your world (if you were ok with faster than light communication) you could say someone made a breakthrough and figured out how to transmit information through quantum entanglement in such a way that the atoms in the receiving teleportation device reorganize themselves to be an exact copy of the atoms in the starting end of the teleportation device. Such a breakthrough does not necessitate FTL travel, and it sounds scientific.

Answer (score 3):

**Tesseracts!**

Eight-cell, C8, octachoron, octahedroid, cubic prism, tetracube, or 4D hypercube. All different names for the same concept, namely traveling through a higher dimension of space. It's like when you take a string, and instead of traveling alongside the two-dimensional length of string, you used your three dimensional powers to touch the ends together. Teleporting just works by touching the two locations together alongside the fourth physical dimension which humans can't perceive.

See *A Wrinkle In Time.*

Comment: Right. So it's just like a wormhole.

Comment: @overlord Where you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

Bob Lazar explains gravity distortion systems on (allegedly) a spacecraft he worked on [in this youtube video, clipped from Joe Rogan's podcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5-BtdM2QoM).  Please ignore the debate or opinions about whether he is telling the truth or deranged in any way; the point is that he explains a type of system which would make sense, I think, to the average reader (or listener) today.  Whether it's true or not is a different story, his explanation *seems* reasonable solely from a (fictional) story-telling perspective.

- Particles are shot at a block of a "special element" (element 115 in Bob Lazar's video).  This could be done in a specific pattern based on the number you typed in.
- These particles creates a gravity distortion field, allowing time/gravity to bend.
- This bending of time and/or gravity allows you to effectively bend the space time continuum from where the block of the "special element" is to some other location (again, directed by the pattern of the particles across the element).
- Moving through this distortion is either teleportation (or the illusion of it).